# Numpy sorting a matrix by column by cycle

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dataframe, sorting

I have this numpy array:

```
array(   
[[  1.        ,   9.        , 565.98653513],  
[  1.        ,   1.        , 973.18466261],  
[  1.        ,  25.        , 803.17747373],  
[  2.        ,   9.        ,  82.56336897],  
[  2.        ,   1.        , 104.69517373],  
[  2.        ,  25.        , 627.01127514],  
[  3.        ,  21.        , 334.07622382],  
[  3.        ,  34.        , 921.37623107],  
[  3.        ,  20.        , 342.08177942],

... ...  ... ...

[ 10.        ,   7.        , 424.29338026],  
[ 10.        ,   0.        , 232.71475407],  
[ 10.        ,   1.        , 330.44846202]])
```

But I want to sort the matrix by the first column in a cycle:  1, 2, 3, ...,10. It should look like this:

```
array(   
[[  1.        ,   9.        , 565.98653513],  
[  2.        ,   9.        ,  82.56336897],  
[  3.        ,  21.        , 334.07622382],  

... ... ... ...  

[ 10.        ,   7.        , 424.29338026], 
[  1.        ,   1.        , 973.18466261],  
[  2.        ,   1.        , 104.69517373],  
[  3.        ,  34.        , 921.37623107],  

... ... ... ...  

[ 10.        ,   0.        , 232.71475407],
[  1.        ,  25.        , 803.17747373],  
[  2.        ,  25.        , 627.01127514],  
[  3.        ,  20.        , 342.08177942],  

... ... ... ...  

[ 10.        ,   1.        , 330.44846202]])
```

How can I do this?

I was thinking of converting it to a dataframe (i.e. pandas) for more sorting options, then covert back to an array...but I don't see a straight forward function to do this.

I appreciate any help or ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your array is named `x`:

```
y = [x[i::10] for i in range(int(len(x)/10))]
y = np.array(y)
y.reshape(x.shape)
print(y)
```

The `x[i:j:k]` notation means `x` *from **i** to **j** with step **k***. So `x[i::10]` mean `x` from **i** to the **end** with step **10**.

See more [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Comment: Yup...that did it!  Now I'm gonna look up the "::" syntax to figure out your first line.  I was thinking a for loop, but what you did was fast.  My array is (100,3), but will be scaled up to about (100k, 3).  Thank you @Pablo C

Comment: I'll add the documentation link

Comment: @foobash Please mark it as accepted and vote if it was helpful :)

Comment: Just figured it out before I saw you update.  :: is "every other". https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.02-the-basics-of-numpy-arrays.html

Comment: I accepted it, but I don't have 15 reputation points yet to publicly upvote.

Comment: Thank you, do some test varying i, j and k and you'll understand it better